# How do I add or subtract a row to an entire pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  | a | b | c |
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
1 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
```

I have a dataframe row (or series) like this:

```
  | a | b | c |
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

I want to subtract the row from the entire dataframe to obtain this:

```
  | a | b | c |
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
1 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) or [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with convert one row `DataFrame` to `Series` - e.g. by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for first row:

```
df = df1.add(df2.iloc[0])
#alternative select by row label
#df = df1.add(df2.loc[0])
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  6  7  8
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2.iloc[0])
a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I was missing the `.iloc[0]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the second dataframe to numpy array:

```
df1 + df2.values
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  6  7  8
```

Comment: Possible solution, but is necessary 100% same columns names and order in both, because here is not alignment (what should be good or not, depends of data)